# Python:synthetic classes

Tags: python, class

I can make a synthetic class `cls1` that inherits from `cls`.

```
>>> class cls(object):
...     def func(self,arg):
...         print 'func',arg
>>> def func1(self):
...     print "func 1 of cls1"
>>> def func2(self):
...     print "func2 of cls1"
>>> d=dict(func1=func1,func2=func2)
>>> cls1=type('cls1',(cls,),d)
```

Everything works as expected:

```
>>> obj=cls1()
>>> obj.func(7)
func 7
```

I can also replace `cls1` with `FOO`:

```
>>> cls1=type('FOO',(cls,),d)
```

that gives me:

```
'cls1': <class '__main__.FOO'>,
```

Does this (changing `__name__` variable) alter the behavior of `cls1` and how (everything still works fine)?

Comment: you have just created an functionally equivalent type with different name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just changing the name of your class, so it should matter only if you rely on the name somehow:

```
>>> type(obj)
__main__.FOO
>>> isintance(obj, cls1)
True
```

That works fine, but what about pickling (that I think rely on the name) ?

For example, before the name change, you can pickle `obj` without any problem. You can't afterwards.

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.FOO'>: it's not found as __main__.FOO
```